# rpcapd - what is the password when not using null authentication

Tags: authentication, networking, raspberry-pi, wireshark

I'm running rpcapd on a Raspberry which serves as a WiFi access point to trace/sniff network traffic by WiFi users.

I can run rpcapd in null authentication mode and access the interfaces from my windows machine using wireshark and it works perfect.

However, I'd like to expose these capture interfaces to multiple users and i thought it might be good to not use null authentication but have at least a little barrier for unwanted users.

If i don't use the "-n" argument, what is the user/pass? I searched Google but i can not really find a source which leads me to the answer.

I tried creating a second user which has a password and ran rpcapd from this users but still if i use these users Linux credentials, wireshark tells me it can not find any interfaces. When i re-run rpcapd with the -n argument everything works.

So... i must have overseen something!? What is the username and password for non null authentication operation or where can i specify one?

Thanks a lot!

Let me know if you need further info to help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When not using RPCAP_RMTAUTH_NULL authentication it will instead use the other type, RPCAP_RMTAUTH_PWD : https://www.winpcap.org/docs/docs_412/html/group__remote__auth__methods.html

And according to some old copy of the manual I found (ftp://ftp.tuwien.ac.at/.vhost/winpcap.polito.it/301a/docs/group__remote__auth__methods.html) which helpfully listed code references : "Referenced by daemon_checkauth(), and rpcap_sendauth()."

..which leads us to to the code that does the authentication : ftp://ftp.tuwien.ac.at/.vhost/winpcap.polito.it/301a/docs/daemon_8c-source.html#l00626

I downloaded the source (http://www.winpcap.org/install/bin/WpcapSrc_4_1_3.zip) to check it was still current and found in file "wpcap\libpcap\rpcapd\daemon.c" the current information for "daemon_AuthUserPwd" which shows not much has changed.

Hope this helps :-)